# Apply css animation when content is in viewport(along with pagepiling.js)

Tags: javascript, html, css, animate.css, pagepiling.js

I am trying to animate the content when it comes in viewport. But the problem is, jquery(for checking that the content is in viewport or not) isn't working as i am also using pagepiling.js (http://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling/).
I don't know the exact reason for this but i think it may be due to position of different pages using pagepiling.js which is creating a problem.
Is there any solution for this?(basically, i want something like [this](https://www.tumblr.com/login))

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="animate.css" />  <!-- animate.css css3 library   -->
<script src="viewportchecker.js"></script>      <!-- viewportchecker plugin   -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.pagepiling.min.js"></script>

<style>
.hidden{
     opacity:0;
}
.visible{
     opacity:1;
}
</style>

<script>
var deleteLog = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#pagepiling').pagepiling({
menu: '#menu',
anchors: ['page1', 'page2', 'page3'],
sectionsColor: ['#bfda00', '#693575', '#2C3E50', '#51bec4'],
easing: 'linear'
});
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.post').addClass("hidden").viewportChecker({
classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeIn',
offset: 100
});
});
</script>

<div id="pagepiling">
    <div class="section" id="section1">
    <div class="intro">
         <div class="post"> <!-- Post content goes here --> </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="section" id="section2">
    <div class="intro">
        <div class="post"> <!-- Post content goes here --> </div>
    </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [pagePiling.js documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/pagePiling.js) you'll find it provides callbacks for you such as [`afterLoad`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/pagePiling.js#afterload-anchorlink-index), [`onLeave`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/pagePiling.js#onleave-index-nextindex-direction)...

Just make use of them like its detailed in the docs:

```
$('#pagepiling').pagepiling({
    anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'fourthPage', 'lastPage'],

    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
        //using index
        if(index == 3){
            alert("Section 3 ended loading");
        }

        //using anchorLink
        if(anchorLink == 'secondPage'){
            alert("Section 2 ended loading");
        }
    }
});
```